# Displaceability of the sublevels below the Mane critical value

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, symplectic-topology

Recently I have been reading the paper "Symplectic topology of  Mané's critical values" by Cielibak, Frauenfelder and Paternain. I am mostly interested in the part of the paper regarding the (non)-displaceability of the sublevels $\Sigma_k:=H^{-1}(k)$, where $H(q,p)=\frac{1}{2}||p||_g^2+U(q)$ is a Hamiltonian defined in $T^*N$ for a closed submanifold $N$, in the situation where the symplectic form $\omega$ is the standard one, so there is no magnectic field, and the Mané critical value is $c=\max_{q\in N}U(q)$.

Now there is an interesting feature about the (non)-displaceability of the subsets $\Sigma$ as $k$ passes through $c$. For $k>c$ we will have that $\Sigma_k$ is regular and furthermore it will be $\textbf{non-displaceable}$. The proof follows from the fact that the Rabinowitz Floer homology of the disk bundle is non-trivial and the invariance of Rabinowitz Floer homology under contact homotopies.

Now for $k<c$ the authors claim that $\Sigma_k$ is $\textbf{displaceable}$. The first observation is that since $k<c$ then the subset $\Sigma_k$ will have to miss at least one fiber. The authors claim that the displaceability of $\Sigma_k$ follows from this fact, however I am not able to create the concrete compactly supported Hamiltonian diffeomorphism that indeed displaces $\Sigma_k$.

Therefore does anyone have an idea on what is the Hamiltonian diffeomorphism that indeed displaces $\Sigma_k$  for $k<c$?

Answer (score 0):

An explicit construction of a displacing Hamiltonian function is given in [Proposition 8.2](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00526-005-0368-z). In the case of electromagnetic Lagrangian functions, the Mané critical value coincides with
$$e_0(L_H) := \inf\{r \in \mathbb{R} : \pi(E^{-1}(r)) = N\}$$
as you can read [here on page 399](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11784-013-0128-1). As your Hamiltonian function is a Tonelli Hamiltonian function, you can certainly switch to the Lagrangian setting via the Legendre transform.